# Nullity guard doesn't work for inside forEach loop

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, flowtype

In the below code, the second guard can't assert non-nullity of `ab.cv` inside the `forEach` loop, where uncommenting a local identical guard makes it work. Why is it so?

```
type B = {|
    bv: B[], 
    cv: ?number
|}

let ab: B = {bv: [], cv: 1}
if (ab.cv) {          // First guard
  const a = ab.cv + 1 // Works
}
var a2;
if (ab.cv) {                                           // Second guard
  ab.bv.forEach(b => {/*if (ab.cv) */a2 = ab.cv + 1})  // Doesn't work except if uncommented
                                                       // Cannot perform arithmetic operation because null or undefined [1] is not a number.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow invalidates refinement done before `forEach` callback. Callback is considered a function call and any function call invalidates the refinement. More info on this in [docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/#toc-refinement-invalidations) and [faq](https://flow.org/en/docs/faq/#toc-i-checked-that-foo-bar-is-not-null-but-flow-still-thinks-it-is-why-does-this-happen-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

One way to get around this is storing checked value in local variable:

```
const cv = ab.cv;
var a2;

if (cv) {
  ab.bv.forEach(b => {a2 = cv + 1})
}
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AIVALygDeAPoqJaAEYBuAXHgNoC6ANKBVQMYOgD8AOwCuAW2pYATolIBfZNCwpQAQ2qN8RYnUasOvRgEZ53WIIDOy3oVXUAdLwDciWismqATM8QBLSKAAKXgBKEi41Ozo7SFhJAFEVbgALAOpCAD4SFQ8bawBqUGNgxFkgA)